# How do I display a website in a Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

How can I display a website simply in a Java GUI?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`WebView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) in your application to render specified webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Why not embed a Java browser such as [Lobobrowser](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) or [JBrowser](http://code.google.com/p/jbrowser/) ?